# Could not find an artifact in central when using maven build a project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, jdom

I'm totally new to Maven. I am building an Apache projects using Maven command: `mvn clean package`.
It showed build failure and give the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project taverna-perspective-myexperiment: Could not 
resolve dependencies for project org.apache.taverna.workbench:taverna-perspective-
myexperiment:bundle:3.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact
org.jdom:com.springsource.org.jdom:jar:1.1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

It seems it needs a dependency org.jdom:com.springsource.org.jdom:jar:1.1.0 but it cannot find it. I searched this artifact in the internet and found [a page](https://javalibs.com/artifact/org.jdom/com.springsource.org.jdom) giving the following maven configurations:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
   <artifactId>com.springsource.org.jdom</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I checked the pom.xml and found the dependency for org.jdom is identical with the above. What should I do to fix it? Does it mean this artifact has been removed from the central? Is there any other sources we can set for it?

Comment: what happens if you move the scope provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[in page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/com.springsource.org.jdom/2.0.1) write note:

Note: this artifact is located at Spring Plugins repository (https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/)

then you must add https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/ to repositories in pom.xml file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring</id>
        <name>Spring Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
       <artifactId>com.springsource.org.jdom</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.0</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```